# Выполнение скрипта только после редиректа в iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать выполнение JS скрипта только после редиректа в `iFrame`? Просто там приходят индивидуальные параметры для каждого пользователя и нужно, чтобы скрипт определял, что произошел редирект в `<iframe>` и только после этого выполнялся.

Comment: `<iframe onload="myFunction()" ...`

Comment: Если страница в `iframe` и родительская страница принадлежат одному домену, то вы можете из iframe через `window.top` вызвать функцию родительской страницы.